# Is there a way to put output of :map to a file or quickfix window? - VIM

Tags: vim

Is there a way to put output of **:map** to a file or quickfix window?
Sometimes I want to copy it or do some search in it. Right now I can just scroll in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
:redir > file
:map
:redir END
:e file
```

See `:help :redir`.

---

Note that the need to search trough the output of `:map` is generally not a problem in itself but a symptom of other problems: too many plugins, using someone else's vimrc… take a look into those problems.

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much, It does work perfectly.